# Get html from site that is rendered with Js

Tags: c#, ajax, xpath

This link leads to a document from an open nutrition database:

```
http://www.dabas.com/ProductSheet/Detail.ashx/124494
```

Im trying to fetch some information from this page with the help from `xpath`.
The problem is this, when i choose "view source", in order to find out what tags I am after, all I get is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <script src="../../js/jquery-1.3.2-vsdoc2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>ProductSheetLoader</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position:absolute; left:50%; top:50%; width:500px; height:200px; margin-top:-100px; margin-left:-266px; padding:15px; color:#666;">
        <h1><img src="../../images/ajax-loader.gif" /> Produktbladet laddas...</h1>
    </div>
    <input id="hiddenARIDENT" name="ARIDENT" type="hidden" value="124494" />
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url2 = "/ProductSheet/Details.ashx/" + $('#hiddenARIDENT').val()

        $.ajax({
            url: url2,
            cache: false,
            success: function (respones) {
                with (window.document) {
                    write(respones);
                    close();
                }
            }
        });

    });

</script>

</html>
```

It seems to me that all the info is getting loaded from somewhere else. 
If i press `f12`, I can see all the info I want but how can I Acess this info? Is it possible?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Generally you would go about using a headless browser to do that such as [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org) or [slimerjs](http://slimerjs.org). They have the same API and can be used with the navigation framework [casperjs](http://casperjs.org). They can also be used with Selenium WebDrivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original page just loads the actual content with ajax, and replaces the document contents with it. The actual information in this case is available at `/ProductSheet/Details.ashx/124494`, (note the **`s`** in `Details.ashx`, which contains the actual page contents.

Generally, the server might check whether the request also contains the `X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest` header, but it does not seem to be the case here.

Comment: Aha! Very interesting, this information will help me a lot. Thank you!